# Oracle ASM database is not started in linux after creation

Tags: oracle, grid

We try to implement ASM database in oracle linux 7 platform

First we installed **oracle grid and database installation 11.2.0.1** completed successfully .

At the time of database creation after reached 86 % is not started , but database is created .

[image: DBCA error]

```
[grid@localhost grid]$ /u01/app/grid/product/11.2.0/grid/bin/srvctl status database -d ram
Database is not running.

[grid@localhost grid]$ /u01/app/grid/product/11.2.0/grid/bin/srvctl start database -d ram 
PRCR-1079: Failed to start resource ora.ram.db

CRS-5017: The resource action "ora.ram.db start" encountered the following error: 

ORA-01078: failure in processing system parameters

. For details refer to "(:CLSN00107:)" in "/u01/app/grid/product/11.2.0/grid/log/localhost/agent/ohasd/oraagent_grid/oraagent_grid.log".


CRS-2674: Start of 'ora.ram.db' on 'localhost' failed
```

I Checked below link and proceed the steps:

- https://levipereira.wordpress.com/2016/09/01/prcr-1079-crs-5017-ora-01017-dbca-fails-to-create-a-database-in-oracle-restart-environment-12c/

but still not able to start a ASM database

contents of oraagent_grid.log

Oracle Database 11g Clusterware Release 11.2.0.4.0 - Production Copyright 1996, 2011 Oracle. All rights reserved.
2018-07-16 21:26:42.215: [ora.LISTENER.lsnr][3174700800]{0:0:2} [check] execCmd ret = 0
2018-07-16 21:27:09.869: [    AGFW][3187115776]{0:0:2} Agent received the message: AGENT_HB[Engine] ID 12293:115784
2018-07-16 21:27:10.771: [ora.evmd][3174700800]{0:0:2} [check] clsdmc_respget return: status=0, ecode=1
2018-07-16 21:27:10.771: [ora.evmd][3174700800]{0:0:2} [check] DaemonAgent::check returned 0
2018-07-16 21:27:10.771: [ora.evmd][3174700800]{0:0:2} [check] Deep check returned 1
2018-07-16 21:27:32.183: [ora.FRA.dg][3189217024]{0:0:967} [check] CrsCmd::ClscrsCmdData::stat entity 1 statflag 33 useFilter 0
2018-07-16 21:27:32.201: [ora.FRA.dg][3189217024]{0:0:967} [check] DgpAgent::runCheck: asm stat asmRet 0
2018-07-16 21:27:32.202: [ora.FRA.dg][3189217024]{0:0:967} [check] DgpAgent::getConnxn connected
2018-07-16 21:27:32.202: [ora.FRA.dg][3189217024]{0:0:967} [check] DgpAgent::queryDgStatus dgName FRA ret 0
2018-07-16 21:27:40.774: [ora.evmd][3189217024]{0:0:2} [check] clsdmc_respget return: status=0, ecode=1
2018-07-16 21:27:40.774: [ora.evmd][3189217024]{0:0:2} [check] DaemonAgent::check returned 0
2018-07-16 21:27:40.774: [ora.evmd][3189217024]{0:0:2} [check] Deep check returned 1
2018-07-16 21:27:42.116: [ora.LISTENER.lsnr][3189217024]{0:0:2} [check] Utils:execCmd action = 3 flags = 38 ohome = (null) cmdname = lsnrctl. 
2018-07-16 21:27:42.219: [ora.LISTENER.lsnr][3189217024]{0:0:2} [check] execCmd ret = 0
2018-07-16 21:28:09.864: [    AGFW][3187115776]{0:0:2} Agent received the message: AGENT_HB[Engine] ID 12293:115800
2018-07-16 21:28:10.776: [ora.evmd][3176802048]{0:0:2} [check] clsdmc_respget return: status=0, ecode=1
2018-07-16 21:28:10.776: [ora.evmd][3176802048]{0:0:2} [check] DaemonAgent::check returned 0
2018-07-16 21:28:10.776: [ora.evmd][3176802048]{0:0:2} [check] Deep check returned 1
2018-07-16 21:28:39.866: [    AGFW][3187115776]{0:0:2} Agent received the message: AGENT_HB[Engine] ID 12293:115808
2018-07-16 21:28:40.778: [ora.evmd][3157808896]{0:0:2} [check] clsdmc_respget return: status=0, ecode=1
2018-07-16 21:28:40.778: [ora.evmd][3157808896]{0:0:2} [check] DaemonAgent::check returned 0
2018-07-16 21:28:40.778: [ora.evmd][3157808896]{0:0:2} [check] Deep check returned 1
2018-07-16 21:28:42.110: [ora.LISTENER.lsnr][3157808896]{0:0:2} [check] Utils:execCmd action = 3 flags = 38 ohome = (null) cmdname = lsnrctl. 
2018-07-16 21:28:42.213: [ora.LISTENER.lsnr][3157808896]{0:0:2} [check] execCmd ret = 0
2018-07-16 21:29:09.868: [    AGFW][3187115776]{0:0:2} Agent received the message: AGENT_HB[Engine] ID 12293:115816
2018-07-16 21:29:10.780: [ora.evmd][3159910144]{0:0:2} [check] clsdmc_respget return: status=0, ecode=1
2018-07-16 21:29:10.780: [ora.evmd][3159910144]{0:0:2} [check] DaemonAgent::check returned 0
2018-07-16 21:29:10.780: [ora.evmd][3159910144]{0:0:2} [check] Deep check returned 1
2018-07-16 21:29:39.869: [    AGFW][3187115776]{0:0:2} Agent received the message: AGENT_HB[Engine] ID 12293:115824
2018-07-16 21:29:40.772: [ora.evmd][3189217024]{0:0:2} [check] clsdmc_respget return: status=0, ecode=1
2018-07-16 21:29:40.772: [ora.evmd][3189217024]{0:0:2} [check] DaemonAgent::check returned 0
2018-07-16 21:29:40.772: [ora.evmd][3189217024]{0:0:2} [check] Deep check returned 1
2018-07-16 21:29:42.114: [ora.LISTENER.lsnr][3189217024]{0:0:2} [check] Utils:execCmd action = 3 flags = 38 ohome = (null) cmdname = lsnrctl. 
2018-07-16 21:29:42.217: [ora.LISTENER.lsnr][3189217024]{0:0:2} [check] execCmd ret = 0
2018-07-16 21:30:10.778: [ora.evmd][3176802048]{0:0:2} [check] clsdmc_respget return: status=0, ecode=1
2018-07-16 21:30:10.778: [ora.evmd][3176802048]{0:0:2} [check] DaemonAgent::check returned 0
2018-07-16 21:30:10.778: [ora.evmd][3176802048]{0:0:2} [check] Deep check returned 1
2018-07-16 21:30:39.863: [    AGFW][3187115776]{0:0:2} Agent received the message: AGENT_HB[Engine] ID 12293:115838
2018-07-16 21:30:40.775: [ora.evmd][3176802048]{0:0:2} [check] clsdmc_respget return: status=0, ecode=1
2018-07-16 21:30:40.775: [ora.evmd][3176802048]{0:0:2} [check] DaemonAgent::check returned 0
2018-07-16 21:30:40.775: [ora.evmd][3176802048]{0:0:2} [check] Deep check returned 1
2018-07-16 21:30:42.118: [ora.LISTENER.lsnr][3176802048]{0:0:2} [check] Utils:execCmd action = 3 flags = 38 ohome = (null) cmdname = lsnrctl. 
2018-07-16 21:30:42.221: [ora.LISTENER.lsnr][3176802048]{0:0:2} [check] execCmd ret = 0
2018-07-16 21:31:09.865: [    AGFW][3187115776]{0:0:2} Agent received the message: AGENT_HB[Engine] ID 12293:115846
2018-07-16 21:31:10.777: [ora.evmd][3157808896]{0:0:2} [check] clsdmc_respget return: status=0, ecode=1
2018-07-16 21:31:10.777: [ora.evmd][3157808896]{0:0:2} [check] DaemonAgent::check returned 0
2018-07-16 21:31:10.777: [ora.evmd][3157808896]{0:0:2} [check] Deep check returned 1

Comment: This error can present itself due to a number of issues - it may be a file permissions issue, or it could be related to a specific bug (e.g.  Bug 16870214 : DB STARTUP FAILS WITH ORA-17510 IF SPFILE IS IN 4K SECTOR SIZE DISKGROUP). 

Can you post the contents of the oraagent_grid.log file?

Comment: Please find the below oraagent_grid.log :

Comment: updated oragent_grid.log  , not able to attach a file in this post .can you please share a email id , let me sent it if needed

Answer (score 1):

For ASM database startup issue in linux , we need to apply a patch for oracle database 11.2.0.4

Patch : 16870214

After applying this patch , Database is able to start . please note it

Comment: Sorry for not responding sooner - things have been busy. Glad to see you were able to figure it out :)